# ASP.NET MVC Tuple

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tuples

In my View i have to put two different Forms and i have to use two different ViewModels. So i decided to use Tuple.
View:

```
@model Tuple<pi.Models.AddNewMechanic,pi.Models.ExistingUser>
```

and I got two forms

But how can i recive it from View in HttpPost Controler?
I tried like that:

```
public ActionResult AddMechanic(Tuple<pi.Models.AddNewMechanic, pi.Models.ExistingUser> model) {}
```

but i got message it cannot find method with parameter, so how I have to implement it inside this method, but there is a question how?

Comment: Normally, you'd use two Partial Views for this, each with its own View Model and form. And since there are two forms, you'd have two different action methods, one for submitting each form. Are your 2 forms supposed to be submitted at once? Or how can you have 1 action method for both?

Comment: Yea i know that every View should have own Model, but in this case i have to send two models, but 1 of it will be null.

Comment: Using a Tuple as parameter won't work with the default model binder and the default action invoker, as you've noticed. You *could* supply your own action invoker, and your own model binder to the action method, a binder that can bind the tuple to its two ingredients. But just making two action methods instead (and one view with two partial views in it (each with its own view model)) would be *hella* easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongelly sugest you create a new Model and inside of your new model, you can put this two object. Take care to dont mix domain model and view model. Otherwise, you will have always this kind of problem.

```
 Domain Model 
 - class a
  - class b


View Model
  - class AB
   prop A, prop B
```

Comment: HYm... it gives me a idea.
I will create 1 big ViewModel which will have prop of two models.
In Post Action i will do binding and use my two smaller other ViewModels which i created before.

Comment: Yes, actually you really should do this. There are a lot of discussion and how to do this. But, you will see that after time you will be able to reuse a lot of code. By the way, cold you mark your question for answered.

Comment: Yea, but i got problem with Validations... When i do areas for New user i got error at ExistingUser beacause i didn't provide any data

Comment: You have to be sure that the name are binding with the name of your properties.

Like A.Name => <input name="A.Name"/>

Comment: I don't understand, I can use  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(). But problem is other. I have few fields ,but some of them are hiden, and if i create new user i don't see fields for Existing user, so they are empty. That's why ValidationMessage throw me the error.

Comment: So, you can retrieve the object again. Update the data that is different and after submit to update.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand.

Comment: ModelState.Remove("model.field"); This fix everything

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do this by the book, which would be:

`AddMechanic.cshtml` has no special view model, but contains two partial views. This is your "page with two forms".

`_AddNewMechanic.cshtml` is the first partial view form, which has `AddNewMechanic` as view model.

`_ExistingUser.cshtml` is the second partial view form, which has `ExistingUser` as view model.

The form in `_AddNewMechanic.cshtml` posts to the `AddNewMechanic` action method, which takes an `AddNewMechanic` as parameter.

The form in `_ExistingUser.cshtml` posts to the `AddExistingMechanic` action method, which takes an `ExistingUser` as parameter.

Upsides:

- No need for any `Tuple` weirdness.
- You can keep your existing View Models.
- Your action method parameters will not normally be null, so no need for weird null checks.
- Easy to follow and understand your code.